# Move starting position for a nested loop after each recursive call

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I'm trying to loop through an array of array, after each iteration, recursively call the function to loop through the arrays again, but one position further along the array of arrays.  Code example below. Temp rows is just an example, the data could change and contain more or less arrays inside the outer array. Is there a way to do it without flattening the array?

```
tempRows = [[1,1,1], 
            [1,1,1], 
            [1,1,1]
            ]
num = 10;
func(start) {
  for (let i = 0; i < tempRows.length; i++) {
      for (let j = start; j < tempRows[i].length; j++) {
        console.log(start) // start is now one element forward
        //then loop through the rest of the elements as usual
       }
  }
 if ( start < num) {
  func(start + 1)
 } 
  return;
  
}
func(0)
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of your data? It will help to understand what you would like. so, specify the starting data, with your sub arrays and list the output that you would like to see.

Comment: Where are you flattening the array?

Comment: You need a check for the base case or you'll have infinite recursion.

Comment: Sorry, up dated with sample data. So, when the function is called, it would then start at position 1 rather than 0 on the first array, and continue until the starting position is the last position. It will always be an array of arrays, but only as deep as nested as the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a condition before each recursion will do the trick. In the following code, only the first two arrays (if they are) of each array will be recursed.

```js
let tempRows = [[0, [1.1, 1.2, 1.3], [2.1, 2.2]], 
                [3, 4, 5], 
                [6, 7, 8]
               ]
           
let limit = 1;


function repeatWithException(multiArray) {

  multiArray.forEach((item, idx) => {
    
    if (!Array.isArray(item))
       console.log(item)
    else
     if (idx <= limit)
       repeatWithException(item);     
  
  })

}


repeatWithException(tempRows)
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for but you put me on the right track so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```js
const data = [[1,2,3,4,5], ['a','b','c','d'], [true, false]]

const print = (input) => 
    (Array.isArray(input)) ? input.forEach(print) : console.log(input)
        
const go = ([first, ...rest]) => 
    first && (print([first, ...rest]), go(rest))

go(data)
```